# String tokenization in C

Tags: c

I am trying to tokenize a string using `strtok` in C. Since the string has multiple delimiters, I use the `strtok` however it fails to tokenize the strings if they have white space.

Example:

```
String to tokenize: Name:Mustafa Baki /Phone:123456789 /Note:real
        char *name = strtok(line," /");
        char *phone = strtok(NULL, " /");
        char *note1 = strtok(NULL," /");

        //tokenize name
        name = strtok(name, ":");
        name = strtok(NULL, ":");
        
        //tokenize phone number
        phone = strtok(phone, ":");
        phone = strtok(NULL, ":");

        //tokenize note

        note1 = strtok(note1, ":");
        note1 = strtok(NULL, ":");
        printf("Name: %s Phone: %s Note: %s \n",name,phone,note1);
```

What I get is `Name: Mustafa Phone: (null) Note: 123456789`  after it prints.

Since the name has white space, it ruins everything. It just skips the phone number as you can see and assigns it to the note.

How can I fix that? Is it possible to take the string as a whole after the delimiter for example let's say that string to be tokenized is `Name:Mustafa Baki`. Can I take `Mustafa Baki` as a whole after `:`? Do I need concatenation or something like that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run to reproduce the problem. The delimiter argument for `strtok` does not specify a delimiter string (`" /"`)  but a set of single-byte delimiter characters (`' '` and `'/'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) uses the second argument as a  *set* to tokenize on. So the string `" /"` will tokenize *either* on space `' '` *or* on slash `'/'`. Not the full string.

That means `name` will be pointing to the single string `"Mustafa"` while `phone` points to `"Baki"` and `note1` points to `"Phone:123456789"`.

You should use *only* the slash `"/"` in the initial calls to `strtok`. Then if needed strip trailing spaces in the strings.